# MVC3 Reuse area in another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I created an area for the signup/signin process of our website and wonder how I in the most effective way can reuse the that area in another project keeping the code at the same place. The code consists of Controllers and views.

Can I somehow externalize the whole thing to another project so that I can include a dll to both websites?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the item as a link:
[Adding an Existing Item as a Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a project only with the area in it.
and package the project with nuget.
and install the nuget package to each of your websites.

you have to install the nuget package manually though if your area get updated. or you have to write your pre-build script to reinstall it automatically.